# Repeat of SQL Server error “An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected.”

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Reading other posts regarding very similar errors, I believe my circumstance is a bit different.  Here's the code:

```
DELETE FROM comp_system_location
WHERE (system_id, location_id) IN
    (
    SELECT 
        csl.system_id,
        csl.location_id
    FROM comp_system_location AS csl
        INNER JOIN orgn_location AS ol ON csl.location_id = ol.location_id
    WHERE 
        ol.building_id IN (1, 3, 4)
        AND 
            (
            csl.system_id IN (29, 35)
            AND csl.location_id NOT IN (40, 41, 43, 44, 46, 47)
            )
        OR
            (
            csl.system_id NOT IN (29, 35)
            AND csl.location_id IN (40, 41, 43, 44, 46, 47)
            )
    );
```

The reason I feel this is a bit different is the my comparison for the WHERE clause is IN.  The error is being thrown on `system_id` in `WHERE (system_id,location_is) IN`

From other suggestion on deleting rows based on multiple columns, this should work.  But I've been wrong before...  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't support tuples in `IN`. You need to rewrite as `EXISTS` or a `JOIN`. `EXISTS` is closest as both represent a semi join so this is shown below.

```
WITH ToDelete
     AS (SELECT csl.system_id,
                csl.location_id
         FROM   comp_system_location AS csl
                INNER JOIN orgn_location AS ol
                  ON csl.location_id = ol.location_id
         WHERE  ol.building_id IN ( 1, 3, 4 )
                AND ( csl.system_id IN ( 29, 35 )
                      AND csl.location_id NOT IN ( 40, 41, 43, 44,
                                                   46, 47 ) )
                 OR ( csl.system_id NOT IN ( 29, 35 )
                      AND csl.location_id IN ( 40, 41, 43, 44,
                                               46, 47 ) ))
DELETE csl
FROM comp_system_location csl
WHERE EXISTS 
(
SELECT * 
FROM ToDelete td
WHERE td.system_id = csl.system_id AND  td.location_id = csl.location_id 
);
```

It may be unnecessary to reference `comp_system_location` in the CTE but I don't know your data model or desired semantics.

Possibly you just need

```
DELETE csl
FROM   comp_system_location AS csl
       INNER JOIN orgn_location AS ol
         ON csl.location_id = ol.location_id
WHERE  ol.building_id IN ( 1, 3, 4 )
       AND ( csl.system_id IN ( 29, 35 )
             AND csl.location_id NOT IN ( 40, 41, 43, 44,
                                          46, 47 ) )
        OR ( csl.system_id NOT IN ( 29, 35 )
             AND csl.location_id IN ( 40, 41, 43, 44,
                                      46, 47 ) );
```

This isn't exactly the same semantics as your `IN` version but possibly what you are trying to do?

Comment: The second option is what I ended up with.  Thank you Martin!  It worked perfectly.